# Should I mention that I know someone who works for the company I am going to interview for?

Tags: interviewing

I last saw him five years ago but he was friendly. He is now a manager. We were part of an NGO. I was starting working there while he was the president.

Please, take into account that I do not live in USA. I live in a country where people are much more informal (casual).

Comment: Welcome to the site Michael. I see that you've posted [two](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64977/do-you-know-anyone-who-works-for-us-interview-question) [questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64976/should-i-mention-that-i-know-someone-who-works-for-the-company-i-am-going-to-int) about a similar topic. I guess they have a different focus and different answers though so I suppose that should be fine.

Comment: You can if you want to, but you're under no obligation to. I am surprised you didn't send that person your resume in the first place. Resumes that get forwarded from an internal employee usually get more weight and more consideration than a resume that comes directly from outside. That being said, if there is a good reason you didn't go through him, like he doesn't like you, or he doesn't think you're a good worker, then it's probably a good idea that you don't mention his name at all.

Comment: Please don't ask two almost identical questions. If you need to amend your initial question, you should just use the 'edit' link next to it. http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64977/do-you-know-anyone-who-works-for-us-interview-question

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how close you were to the person. If you actually considered them a friend, as in you'd hang out on the weekends, then sure. If you'd worked closely with projects, maybe, but only if he'd really remember you.

Name dropping is something I typically suggest against, because you never know how the person you're talking to feels about that other person, and even worse, if they ask the other person about you and they have no memory of it, then that could be a dealbreaker.